# Windows Event handing in Java

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and I'd like to know how to handle Windows' events in Java. To be specific, I'd like to know how to handle events such as mouse moved or mouse clicked in Windows XP and Windows Vista. I want to wire my own custom behavior in my application to these events, even when my application is inactive or otherwise hidden.

Comment: Swing or SWT? (Swing is the window toolkit for Java that comes with the JDK; SWT is an alternative)

Answer (score 6):

Check this out: [Implementing Listeners for Commonly Handled Events](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html).